# Need exercises to learn the Gurobi python package syntax

Tags: python, gurobipy

as I am trying to learn the Gurobi package, I did successfully try to implement some mathematical models. I want more and wish to have some exercises containing the Obj fun solution and the variables as well please.

Comment: It's as simple as checking gurobi's own site or [github](https://github.com/Gurobi/modeling-examples). for example:  https://www.gurobi.com/jupyter_models/

Comment: Thanks for proposing this but I did these.

Comment: Those are plenty of models, each with different difficulty and features. You can see the solution of all of those by just running them and confirming that you also implemented them correctly yourself. Other than that and unless you specify what exactly you're after, I say that's sufficient.